# Can we access the members of sub class using the refrenced variable of super class which holds the subclass object?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

If not,then for the below program, how is the **multiplication**(method) of subclass is accessed Since I used the refrence variable of superclass **Calculation** which holds object of subclass **My_Calculation**.
***Output of below program is:**
The sum of the given numbers:30
The difference between the given numbers:10
The product of the given numbers in sub class is:200*

```
class Calculation {
int z;

public void addition(int x, int y) {
   z = x + y;
   System.out.println("The sum of the given numbers:"+z);
}

public void Subtraction(int x, int y) {
   z = x - y;
   System.out.println("The difference between the given numbers:"+z);
}
public void multiplication(int x, int y) {
   z = x * y;
   System.out.println("The product of the given numbers in super class is :"+z);
}
}

public class My_Calculation extends Calculation {
public void multiplication(int x, int y) {
   z = x * y;
   System.out.println("The product of the given numbers in sub class is:"+z);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
   int a = 20, b = 10;
   Calculation demo = new My_Calculation();
   demo.addition(a, b);
   demo.Subtraction(a, b);
   demo.multiplication(a, b);
}
}
```

I was expecting error since we can only access the member of super class using the refrence of super class.

Comment: Where exactly were you expecting an error?

Comment: @JonSkeet Actually I was expecting an error since we can only access the member of the superclass using the reference of the superclass.

Comment: Try removing the `multiplication` method from the parent class.

Comment: Although you have the reference of the parent class, your actual object is of the child class. Which method will be called at runtime is dependent on the actual object not the reference type.

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Names should be camelCase. *public class My_Calculation extends Calculation {* --> *public class MyCalculation extends Calculation {*

Comment: @Yousaf I know I would get an error if I removed the multiplication method from the parent class. But that's the question why is the sub-class multiplication get called? Since we know we can only access the members of the superclass using the reference variable of superclass Calculation which holds the object of a subclass

Comment: @RifatRubayatulIslam then why would we get an error if we remove multiplication from the superclass since runtime is dependent on the actual object, not the reference type?

Comment: To understand this, you need to know about compile-time type and runtime type. In your code, the compile-time type is the parent type but runtime type is the child type. At compile-time, compiler allows calling only those methods that are defined in the compile-time time, i.e., the parent class in your case. This is why removing the multiplication method from the parent throws an error. Now at runtime, the actual method that is called depends on the runtime type, i.e., the child class in your case.

Comment: "Actually I was expecting an error since we can only access the member of the superclass using the reference of the superclass" - that doesn't answer my question at all. It just repeats what you'd already written in the question. *Where* were you expecting the error? Which line, and why? (Where do you believe your code accesses a member without that member being present in the superclass?)

Answer (score 0):

A subclass has same method with its super class in java is called **method overriding**.
When an overridden method is called through a superclass reference, Java determines which version(superclass/subclasses) of that method is to be executed. Which method is called is determined by the type of the object being referred to, but not the type of the reference variable.
This is Runtime Polymorphism in Java.

In your code, the **multiplication** method of subclass is called, because the object's real type is *My_Calculation*